# GRUB exhibiting strange behavior after upgrade to ubuntu 20.4

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, grub

I have a dual-boot system with windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04. I recently upgraded to ubuntu 20.4 and my grub menu has started to exhibit strange behavior. When the upgrade was complete and I restarted the system, everything went fine. I booted into linux did some stuff and then shut down the system. When I booted into windows the next time I powered up the PC and shut it down, the grub menu disappeared when I booted my PC again. My system booted into windows directly and I had to shut down once again and start up my PC to get to the grub screen. This doesn't happen when I boot into linux. I can shut down and when I power up my machine, the grub screen is the first thing that comes up. However, If I boot into windows and shut down, when I power up my PC the next time, the grub screen doesn't come up and I am booted directly into windows. I have to shut down the PC and power it up again to get to the grub menu. Every time I need to switch from windows to linux, I need to shut down, boot into windows and then shut down again to be able to switch.

I tried playing around with the etc/default/grub file and changing the timeout values of grub screen but it didn't have any impact.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

I have been looking around I have found a few more things that stand out. I have a 1TB HDD and a 256 GB ssd. The windows OS is installed on the SSD, the 1 TB HDD is split into 2 partitions. 700 gb belongs to windows and 300 GB was set apart for the ubuntu installation where it is currently installed. When I was using ubuntu 18.04, I could boot into ubuntu, go to the "other locations" tab in file manager and view and interact with my windows files in my ubuntu partition. The files inside the windows partition were accessible to me via the ubuntu partition. However, now, after the 20.04 upgrade, I cannot see the windows partition when I'm using ubuntu. The only thing that I can see is the root folder of my ubuntu partition when I access "other places".

The other 2 partitions that were reserved for my windows OS are hidden/inaccessible via ubuntu. I can boot into windows without any problems but I cannot access the files of those partitions when I am using ubuntu. This was not the case when I was using 18.04. I suspect it has something to do with the initial problem.

Comment: Can you see something like 'uefi hard disk drive bbs priorities' in you BIOS settings. If so, try increasing the priority of ubuntu.

Comment: I have done that. Ubuntu is at the top of my boot preference menu in the UEFI firmware settings.

Comment: Sounds like you have _fast startup_ enabled in Windows. Does it work (grub, access ntfs partitions) if you [disable fast startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html) (or try holding the Shift key while selecting "Shutdown")?

Comment: I have fast startup disabled. I disabled it when I first created the dual-boot system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my system was resolved when I used lsblk to view my existing partitions and used fsck to repair the file systems that were not showing up in the file manager.

Atleast I think that is what happened because the missing partitions appeared after that and the whole booting-directly-into-windows-without-showing-the-grub-screen  problem resolved itself.